# How to set a table field Not Null in Laravel 5.4 migration

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 migrations.There is nullable() options . But how Can I set a table field as Not null in Laravel 5.4 migrations ?

Comment: `Not null` is every field which doesn't get the `nullable` option. So if you want your field `Not null` remove the `->nullable()` call.

Comment: So it is default Not null if  I dont use nullable ?

Comment: Yes, a field can only be `null` or `not null` and `->nullable()` allow the field to be null. So without it the field is `not null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is automatically not null if you didn't add nullable() method on your migration.

```
$table->string('col_test1')->nullable();  
//This can be  null. It will run a mysql statement like this
col_test1 VARCHAR(255)

$table->string('col_test2');         
//This should not be null . It will run a mysql statement like this
col_test2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
```

If you want more details just navigate [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#column-modifiers)

Answer (score 2):

A database field can only be `null` or `not null`.

So for laravel if you call `->nullable()` in the migration you allow the field to be `null`  otherwise it is `not null` without any specific configuration.

example

```
// this will be not null
$table->string('col1');
// this can be null
$table->string('col1')->nullable();
```